# Algorithm concerning orthogonal matrices

Tags: algorithm, matrix, orthogonal

Say I have a n-dimensional orthogonal matrix, with some of its elements given and these others unknown. Does there exist an effective algorithm to find out the unknown elements and restore the whole matrix (it only needs to find one solution if there are many, and gives an error when no solution exists)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution depends on how many element per row/column is missing.

- I can see two ways how to approach this

**1. max 1 element missing per row/column**

- in this case you can exploit that any row / column of orthogonal matrix is unit vector
- so for any row/column `{ a1,a2,a3=??,a4,...,an }`
- the unknown element is `a3=sqrt(1-a1^2-a2^2-a4^2-a5^2-...-an^2)`
- if you have more then one unknown elements in row use column and vice versa
- if there is too many unknowns in row and columns at the same time
- then you need to use different approach for that element

**2. more then 1 missing element**

- first find all unknowns that can be found by approach 1
- then you can exploit that `Inverse(Q)==Transpose(Q)` if `Q` is orthogonal
- so derive algebraic formula per unknown element from inverse Q
- and compare it to transposed one
- this will create one linear equation
- do this for all unknowns and solve the system

  ```
       a11 a12     a13
  Q =  a21 a22=?? a23=??
       a31 a32=?? a33=??

                    a11 a21 a31
  transpose(Q) =  a12 a22=?? a32=??
                    a13 a23=?? a33=??

               i11 i12 i13
  inverse(Q)= i21 i22 i23
               i31 i32 i33

  det=a11.a22.a33+a21.a32.a13+a31.a12.a23-a11.a32.a23-a31.a22.a13-a21.a12.a33
  a22=i22=(a11.a33-a13.a31)/det
  a32=i23=(a13.a21-a11.a23)/det
  a23=i32=(a12.a31-a11.a32)/det
  a33=i33=(a11.a22-a12.a21)/det
  ```
- this should be solvable ...
- if not then you can also add equations from bullet 1
- if still not then either solution cant be found or you need to use different approach

**Before computing you should check first if the `|elements|` are not too big**

- so sum all the known elements^2 in row/column and the result should be `<=1`
- if not then this is nor orthogonal matrix ...
- for more info see [Orthogonal matrixes (Wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix)

**3. if you have element=1.0**

- then all elements in that row/column will be zero